# Use Mockito to mock java.nio.file.Files static methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to understand how you can mock static methods, specifically from the static Files.class.

Basically, whenever this line executes:

```
 Files.newInputStream(this.getPathObj(), StandardOpenOption.READ);
```

I want it to just return an object that is an instance of an InputStream.

The is my class with the static method I'm trying to mock.

```
public class JavaFileInput{

private Path path;

public JavaFileInput(Path path){
    this.path = path;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return Files.newInputStream(this.getPathObj(), StandardOpenOption.READ);
}

public Path getPathObj() {
    return this.path;
}

}
```

This is some "psuedo-ish" unit test code that obviously doesn't work, but I hope it portrays the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
@Mock(name="path")
private Path mockedPath = Mockito.mock(Path.class);

@InjectMocks
private JavaFileInput javaFile_MockedPath;

@Before
public void testSetup(){
  javaFile_MockedPath = new JavaFileInput(mockedPath);
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void getNewInputStreamTest(){
    //Setup
    Mockito.when(Files.newInputStream(mockedPathObj, StandardOpenOption.Read)).thenReturn(new InputStream());

    //Test
    InputStream outputValue = javaFile_MockedPath.getInputStream();

    //Validate
    assertTrue(outputValue instanceof InputStream);

}
```

Does this make any sense?  Has anyone ever had to do something similar?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You may want to look at PowerMock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear what value your `JavaFileInput` provides. However, to test static methods you can look at [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

Comment: Romski - Thanks for the response.  I'll look into giving PowerMock a try.  I've seen a lot of other stuff around the net also recommending that tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock using Mockito:

```
mockStatic(Files.class);
when(Files.size(any())).thenReturn(5000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem: I have (own) code which modifies symlinks using nio.Files.

For testing my code without having to prepare and access the file system, I had to write an own mockable wrapper class around these functions.

Not so nice though that the nio JSR didn't consider this use case by defining an official interface and providing a non-static (=injectable) way for accessing `Files`. Mockito was known long before this..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Mockito or PowerMock, you may also use a NIO2 implementation that work in memory:

- [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/glhez/memoryfilesystem)
- [jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs)

While this won't solve all case (or let say it, it won't answer your attempt at mocking a static method) or allow you to create flawed `InputStream` (for example, one that would return an error when reading N bytes), this may suit your use case.

Also you ask if your case make any sense:

```
//Setup
Mockito.when(Files.newInputStream(mockedPathObj, StandardOpenOption.Read)).thenReturn(new InputStream());

//Test
InputStream outputValue = javaFile_MockedPath.getInputStream();

//Validate
assertTrue(outputValue instanceof InputStream);
```

You are testing that `outputValue` is indeed an instance of `InputStream`, which the compiler already does for you: `outputValue` is already an instance of `InputStream`, therefore asserting it is an instance of `InputStream` will never fails and your test is not checking what you want to check.

You'd best to test that `outputValue` is exactly the same instance as one returned, using a mock rather than `new InputStream` for example:

```
InputStream is = mock(InputStream.class);
Mockito.when(Files.newInputStream(mockedPathObj, StandardOpenOption.Read)).thenReturn(is);
InputStream outputValue = javaFile_MockedPath.getInputStream();
assertTrue(outputValue == is);
```

Answer (score -2):

With standard Mockito, you can't mock static methods -- and I would question your reasons for doing so.

What do you seek to test by mocking the `newInputStream` method? You are merely creating a tautology -- that your method returns what you told it to return. And `instanceof InputStream` is a tautology as well.

It would make more sense to mock `JavaFileInput` to test another class that depends on it (perhaps by using a `ByteArrayInputStream` with sample data).

Comment: Tom G - Thanks for the prompt response!  I guess I'm just wanting to test to make sure that getInputStream() is returning an InputStream instance and that's all.  Should I be testing for something else?  There's actually a bunch of static methods from Files.class that I would like to mock, such as Files.exists() and Files.isDirectory(), etc.  I was just hoping to figure out how to handle this test before trying the others.